# MATLAB classification trees (fitctree)

Tags: matlab, decision-tree

I tried to build a classification tree for the following table:
http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-211115-014315.php

The script I wrote is as following (after consulting the documentation and previous questions on this forum):

```
TBL = [1,1,1,0,1,0 ; 2,1,1,1,0,1 ; 3,0,0,1,0,0 ; 4,0,1,0,1,0 ;...
    5,1,0,1,1,1 ; 6,0,0,1,1,0 ; 7,1,0,0,0,0 ; 8,0,1,1,1,1];
DT = fitctree(TBL(:,2:5), TBL(:,6), 'SplitCriterion', 'deviance',...
    'CategoricalPredictors','all');
view(DT,'mode','graph')
```

Yeah... The table is only an image on a PDF so I had to write it by myself...
Anyway, I got a nullified tree: http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-211115-074929.php

Does anyone know what the problem in the script is?
Thanks ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ok to be irritated by the fact that the problem was working with only 8 samples in the training set, isn't it? I don't see any mentioning of it in documentation

so my fix is basically duplicating TBL. works like magic (no need to care for the first column here, as it remained unused anyway):

```
TBL = [1,1,1,0,1,0 ; 2,1,1,1,0,1 ; 3,0,0,1,0,0 ; 4,0,1,0,1,0 ;...
    5,1,0,1,1,1 ; 6,0,0,1,1,0 ; 7,1,0,0,0,0 ; 8,0,1,1,1,1];
TBL = [TBL;TBL];
TBL = [TBL;TBL];

DT = fitctree(TBL(:,2:5), TBL(:,6), 'SplitCriterion', 'deviance',...
    'CategoricalPredictors','all');
view(DT,'mode','graph')
```

[image]